# Field Extension of the Rationals

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory

So I'm considering a Field $\mathbb{F}$, such that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{F}$ and when it's considered a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, it has dimension 2.  I want to show two things:

1) There exists an element a of $\mathbb{F}$ that's not in $\mathbb{Q}$ such that it satisfies the equation $a^2-n=0$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

2) That $\mathbb{F}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[\surd(n)]$ and further that $n$ is square-free.

So, showing there's an element in the complement of $\mathbb{F}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ I've managed, but I can't show that it satisfies the equation in question.  For number 2, I'm lost.

(Trying LaTeX, hope I didn't screw it up too bad.)

Comment: There are many elements in $\mathbb F \setminus \mathbb Q$.  Not all of them satisfy $a^2-n=0$.  The point is that given some $b \in \mathbb F \setminus \mathbb Q$ you can find a related $a$ that works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**A start:** Let $\alpha\in \mathbb{F}$, with $\alpha\not\in \mathbb{Q}$. Argue that by dimensionality considerations, $\alpha^2$, $\alpha$, and $1$ are linearly dependent over the rationals.

This shows that $\alpha$ is the root of a quadratic with rational (or equivalently integer) coefficients.

Complete the square, or use the Quadratic Formula, to produce the requisite $n$ (think discriminant).

Comment: Is it as simple as the discriminant has to be 0 since alpha can't have more than one value?

Comment: The discriminant is definitely not zero. The quadratic will have two solutions. I will assume you got to there are integers $a$, $b$, $c$ with $a\ne 0$ such that $a\alpha^2+b\alpha+c=0$. Let $b^2-4ac=k^2n$ where $n$ is squae-free (this is for later, not needed now). Argue that a linear combination of $\alpha$ and $1$ has square equal to $n$.

Comment: @AsinglePANCAKE: To help thinking, pretend the quadratic turned out to be $2x^2-4x-9$.  Then $n$ turns out to be $22$.

Comment: bah.  still confused.  apologies.  How do I know that the discriminant is k^2*n?

Comment: No, the discriminant is (say) $b^2-4ac$ as usual. Let $k^2$ be largest square that divides the discriminant, and define $n$ by $b^2-4ac=k^2n$. Or else, but you will have to change your mind in a later part of the question, just let $n=b^2-4ac$. In the numerical example I suggested, suppose the linear relation turned out to be $2\alpha^2-4\alpha-9=0$. Find $\alpha$ (one of the roots). Discriminant is $88$. Then it turns out that $\mathbb{F}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, which is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{22})$.

Comment: alright, so methinks I'm with you so far.  Is it enough for the isomorphism to show that the two spaces have (quite obviously) the same basis.  Or am I missing the mark again?

Comment: The field $\mathbb{F}$ need not be a subfield of the reals, but it is isomorphic to it, via the mapping that takes $\alpha$ to either root of the quadratic. Same basis is not enough, that only shows they are isomorphic as vector spaces. Need to show the mapping preserves multiplication also.

Comment: Ah, okay.  Thanks you original combination of original members of the Bourbaki troupe!